# Find the maximum product of two non overlapping palindromic subsequences

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to find the maximum product of two non overlapping palindromic sub-sequences of string `s` that we'll refer to as `a` and `b`. I came up with below code but it's not giving correct output:

```
public static int max(String s) {
    int[][] dp = new int[s.length()][s.length()];

    for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        dp[i][i] = 1;
        for (int j = i+1; j < s.length(); j++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)) {
                dp[i][j] = dp[i+1][j-1] + 2;
            } else {
                dp[i][j] = Math.max(dp[i+1][j], dp[i][j-1]);
            }
        }
    }
    return dp[0][s.length()-1];
}
```

For input string "acdapmpomp", we can choose `a` = "aca" and `b` ="pmpmp" to get a maximal product of score 3 * 5 = 15. But my program gives output as 5.

Comment: @nbrooks they do .. they are not exactly substrings but are a nonoverlapping palindromes.

Comment: @flash To start off, `for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        dp[i][i] = 1;` shouldn't the initialisation be separated out from the processing loops?

Comment: above link also gives same output as 5 just like my program.

Comment: @TharakaRatnayake it seams the question was deleted

Comment: A) I find your requirements to be unclear. What should happen for example when your input string contains 0, 1, or 3 palindromes? B) Your first goal should be to get to **correct** results. Meaning: write the most simple code possible. As in: first write code that **extracts** the palindromes as strings. Why? Because then you can first focus on that part of the problem (what are the valid palindromes). You can write unit tests for that, and instead of looking at int counters (which are really hard to interpret), you can look at strings and substrings. Then, when that works ....

Comment: then you can continue and do the computations you want to do. And then, in the end, when you have working code that gives the correct results (and plenty of test cases that verify that code already) ... then you go in and **refactor** the solution (in case you find its performance insufficient. That is the real thing here: do not solve all at once, rather dissect your problem into the smallest parts possible. Solve those, then build your overall solution from the smaller parts.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly you should traverse the dp table to find out the length of longest palindromic subsequences using bottom up approach, then you can calculate the max product by multiplying dp[i][j] with dp[j+1][n-1] : Given below is the code in C++;

```
int longestPalindromicSubsequenceProduct(string x){
int n = x.size();
vector<vector<int>> dp(n,vector<int>(n,0));
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    dp[i][i] = 1;
}
for(int k=1;k<n;k++){
for(int i=0;i<n-k;i++){
        int j = i + k;
            if(x[i]==x[j]){
                dp[i][j] = 2 + dp[i+1][j-1];
            } else{
                dp[i][j] = max(dp[i][j-1],dp[i+1][j]);
            }
   }
}
int maxProd = 0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<n-1;j++){
        maxProd = max(maxProd,dp[i][j]*dp[j+1][n-1]);
      }
   }
return maxProd;
}
```

Comment: I think this approach is not correct. Try it on ```bacbac```. The answer should be 9 ( for substrings ```bab``` and ```cac```). Your code is printing 3

Comment: The question says "non overlapping palindromic sub-sequences". bab & cac are overlapping. Hope that helps.

Comment: + @rupinderg00 this approach is incorrect , try on "aebgcbea"   {"abcba" , "ege" } ans = 15 , this code will print 5 , as you are considering that each palindromic sub string would be on either half

Comment: @SumitJoshi abcba and ege are overlapping.. we are looking for non overlapping :)

Answer (score 1):

```
int multiplyPalindrome(string s) {
int n=s.size(),m=0;
vector<vector<int>> dp(n, vector<int> (n));
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) dp[i][i]=1;

 for (int cl=2; cl<=n; cl++) {
    for (int i=0; i<n-cl+1; i++){
        int j = i+cl-1; 
        if (s[i] == s[j] && cl == 2) dp[i][j] = 2; 
        else if (s[i] == s[j]) dp[i][j] = dp[i+1][j-1] + 2; 
        else dp[i][j] = max(dp[i][j-1], dp[i+1][j]); 
    } 
}
for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
   m = max( m, dp[0][i]*dp[i+1][n-1] );
} 
return m;
```

}

Comment: I think this approach is not correct. Try it on ```bacbac```. The answer should be 9 ( for substrings ```bab``` and ```cac```). Your code is printing 3.

Answer (score 1):

```
    int palSize(string &s, int mask) {
    int p1 = 0, p2 = s.size(), res = 0;
    while (p1 <= p2) {
        if ((mask & (1 << p1)) == 0)
            ++p1;
        else if ((mask & (1 << p2)) == 0)
            --p2;
        else if (s[p1] != s[p2])
            return 0;
        else
            res += 1 + (p1++ != p2--);
    }
    return res;
}
int maxProduct(string s) {
    int mask[4096] = {}, res = 0;
    for (int m = 1; m < (1 << s.size()); ++m)
        mask[m] = palSize(s, m);
    for (int m1 = 1; m1 < (1 << s.size()); ++m1)
        if (mask[m1])
            for (int m2 = 1; m2 < (1 << s.size()); ++m2)
                if ((m1 & m2) == 0)
                    res = max(res, mask[m1] * mask[m2]);
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all non-overlapping palindromic subsequences and return the maximum value.

```java
  public int longestPalindromicSubsequenceProduct(String str) {
    int maxProduct = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < str.length(); k++) {
      String left = str.substring(0, k);
      String right = str.substring(k);
      int currProduct = longestPalindromicSubsequence(left) * longestPalindromicSubsequence(right);
      maxProduct = Math.max(maxProduct, currProduct);
    }

    return maxProduct;
  }

  private int longestPalindromicSubsequence(String org) {
    String rev = new StringBuilder(org).reverse().toString();
    return longestCommonSubsequence(org, rev);
  }

  private int longestCommonSubsequence(String str1, String str2) {
    int rows = str1.length();
    int cols = str2.length();

    int[][] dp = new int[rows + 1][cols + 1];

    for (int r = 1; r <= rows; r++) {
      for (int c = 1; c <= cols; c++) {
        if (str1.charAt(r - 1) == str2.charAt(c - 1)) dp[r][c] = 1 + dp[r - 1][c - 1];
        else dp[r][c] = Math.max(dp[r - 1][c], dp[r][c - 1]);
      }
    }

    return dp[rows][cols];
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Your algorithm returns the maximum length of a palyndrome, not the maximum of the product of two lengths.

UPDATE

Here's a possible solution:

```
public static int max(String s) {
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < s.length()-1; ++i) {
        String p1 = bestPalyndrome(s, 0, i);
        String p2 = bestPalyndrome(s, i, s.length());
        int prod = p1.length()*p2.length();
        if (prod > max) {
            System.out.println(p1 + " " + p2 + " -> " + prod);
            max = prod;
        }
    }
    return max;
}

private static String bestPalyndrome(String s, int start, int end) {
    if (start >= end) {
        return "";
    } else if (end-start == 1) {
        return s.substring(start, end);
    } else  if (s.charAt(start) == s.charAt(end-1)) {
        return s.charAt(start) + bestPalyndrome(s, start+1, end-1)
                + s.charAt(end-1);
    } else {
        String s1 = bestPalyndrome(s, start, end-1);
        String s2 = bestPalyndrome(s, start+1, end);
        return s2.length() > s1.length() ? s2 : s1;
    }
}
```